# Combine 2 nested dictionary values into one Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I have the following 2 dict, I would like to combine update the `dict1` with the values of `dict2` like following. adds the new keys if doesn't exist,and update the values.

dict1

```
{'https://site1.com': 
{'React': None, 'Drupal': '5.1','python':None}}
```

dict2

```
{'https://site1.com':
{'React': '6.0', 'Drupal': '5.3','PHP':'7'},
'https://site2.com':{'Rails':'6.1'}}
```

to the following output:

final_dict

```
{'https://site1.com': 
{'React': '6.0', 'Drupal': '5.3','PHP':'7','python':None},
'https://site2.com':{'Rails':'6.1'}}
```

Comment: Not an duplicate

Comment: Indeed it's not a duplicate, my bad. Hadn't noticed the dicts have different sub-dicts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can iterate through the items of `dict2` and update `dict1` with values of the same keys. Use the `dict.setdefault` method to initialize new keys with a dict:

```
for k, v in dict2.items():
    dict1.setdefault(k, {}).update(v)
```

With your sample input, `dict1` would become:

```
{'https://site1.com': {'React': '6.0', 'Drupal': '5.3', 'python': None, 'PHP': '7'}, 'https://site2.com': {'Rails': '6.1'}}
```

Answer (score 2):

```py
final_dict = {**dict1, **dict2}
```

(that's for Python 3.5+)

Comment: This would not merge the sub-dicts.

Comment: @blhsing I guess you're right, apparently it just overrides the sub-dicts.

Answer (score 1):

Does `final_dict = dict1.update(dict2)` not work?
[Resource](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/dictionary/update)

Edit: wow, in fact it doesn't. Luca's answer is correct.

Answer (score 1):

Iterate the keys in two dict, if both has value, choose the larger one(in my understanding), support sub-dict by combining them recursively:

update: sorry, I misunderstand, you want to use dict2's value when both has value.

```
def combine_dict(dict1, dict2):
    final_dict = {}
    # iterate keys in two dict
    for k in dict1.keys() | dict2.keys():
        v1 = dict1.get(k, None)
        v2 = dict2.get(k, None)
        if isinstance(v1, dict) or isinstance(v2, dict):
            if not v1: v1 = {}
            if not v2: v2 = {}
            # combine recursively
            final_dict[k] = combine_dict(v1, v2)
        else:
            final_dict[k] = v2
            # if v1 and v2:
            #     final_dict[k] = max(v1, v2)
            # else:
            #     final_dict[k] = v1 or v2
    return final_dict

def test():
    dict1 = {'https://site1.com': {'React': None, 'Drupal': '5.1', 'python': None}}
    dict2 = {'https://site1.com': {'React': '6.0', 'Drupal': '5.3', 'PHP': '7'}, 'https://site2.com': {'Rails': '6.1'}}
    final_dict = {'https://site1.com': {'React': '6.0', 'Drupal': '5.3', 'PHP': '7', 'python': None},
                  'https://site2.com': {'Rails': '6.1'}}
    print(final_dict == combine_dict(dict1, dict2))     # output true
```

Hope that will help you, and comment if you have further questions. : )